# How to flush cache on firebase custom domain?

Tags: varnish, firebase-hosting

All right working in application subdomain and working cache rules for Firebase application subdomain, but at custom domain doesn't flush cache, and return very very old version html, js and css.

I don't understand and don't find how to flush cache on custom domain.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to flush the cached CDN versions of files in Firebase Hosting is to deploy a new version of your site.

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Even if there are no changes, redeploying will tell the CDN edges to clear any data they have.

If that doesn't work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.